# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{...}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on my react app and I use typeScript since few weeks, but I still have some problems to type some variables sometime.

here is the error message :

```
TypeScript error in /Users/SignUpFields.tsx(66,9):
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to     
index type '{ first_name: string; last_name: string; email: string; phone_number: string;     
address: string; adeli: string; password: string; passwordConfirmation: string; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ first_name: 
string; last_name: string; email: string; phone_number: string; address: string; adeli: 
string; password: string; passwordConfirmation: string; }'.  TS7053
```

interface :

```
interface IUserData {
 first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
  phone_number: string;
  address: string;
  adeli: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirmation: string;
}
```

my function :

```
handleChanges = (key: string) => (
event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>
) => {
    let { userData } = this.state;
    let obj: ISignUpFieldsState = this.state;
    for (const k of Object.keys(userData)) {
      if (k ===key){
        console.log('k', k , key);
        userData[k] = event.currentTarget.value;
        this.setState({ userData }, () => this.props.handleChangeFields(obj));
      }
    }
  };
```

There is a thing! I want to modify my state with the key value to keep it generic, and keep in the same time the interface with every props (first_name, ...) to have something very precise.
I saw something like this : `[key: string]: string;` but I don't really like it, cause you 'loose' your props from obj and it look like 'any' type...

Thx and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
handleChanges = <T extends extends keyof IUserData>(key: T) => (
event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>
) => {
    let { userData } = this.state;
    let obj: ISignUpFieldsState = this.state;
    for (const k of Object.keys(userData)) {
      if (k === key){
        console.log('k', k , key);
        userData[key] = event.currentTarget.value;
        this.setState({ userData }, () => this.props.handleChangeFields(obj));
      }
    }
  };
```

Now typescript knows that key can only be one of the valid keys from IUserData.

Also a good practice is to never mutate state, but to always return a new reference(in the example above you are directly mutating the userData  object), so this is even better:

```
    handleChanges = <T extends keyof IUserData>(key: T) => (
    event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    ) => {
    let { userData } = this.state;
    let obj: ISignUpFieldsState = this.state;
    for (const k of Object.keys(userData)) {
      if (k === key){
        console.log('k', k , key);
        userData = {...userData , [key]: event.currentTarget.value};
        this.setState({ userData }, () => this.props.handleChangeFields(obj));
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: I never use '<T extends extends keyof IUserData>(key: T)' how can I use it what should I how to read some doc ?

Comment: typescript documentation is a great start: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Woaw very amazing I'm very surprise about what you can do with 'extends' like take the type's keyof the obj thx a lot! (I correct a little thing cause I think you made a misstake) ;) thx!!

Comment: No problem and thx for the edit. Copy paste is the bane of programming :P